# how to update json file on excution of query

Tags: java, php, android, arrays, json

This json file results.json updates on excution of demo.php file. but I want to update my json file on without excuting php file . how it done ?

demo.php

```
  <?php
            header("content-type:application/json");
            require_once("dbConnect.php");

            $sql = "SELECT id ,,fullname,location from upload WHERE status='active'";

            $res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql,$fp);


            $result = array();
            $response = array();

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){

                        $id=$row['id']; 
                        $fullname=$row['fullname'];

                        $description=$row['description'];

                $response[] = array('id'=> $id, 'fullname'=>   $fullname,'description'=>$description);


                        echo " over";
                    }

            $result['posts'] = $response;
            $response['result'] = $result;
            $fp = fopen('results.json', 'a');
            fwrite($fp, json_encode($result));
            fclose($fp);
            echo json_encode($result);
            mysqli_close($conn);

            ?>
```

Comment: Your json file cannot magically update, you are going to need something that runs in order to update the file. Probably the most accessible way for you, other than just running the demo.php through a browser request, would be a cronjob that runs your demo.php file.

Comment: i know that things ..that's why i'm asking to how to do it

Answer (score 0):

You have to clear your problem that, what exactly you want. all code you have that would written in PHP if you not run the php file then that will not execute.
as per my understanding you need to run that script in background ?

you can fire that file from command line.
via jquery or AJAX get/post request.

you need to clear what you want exactly.

Comment: It should be in comment area

Comment: yes but may he not express him self. may he need to run from command line or in cron.